# Can I turn a regular content type into a Commerce product display?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have an existing working site with lots of content. I've come to the realisation that I could actually sell this content. So is there a way to turn my existing content type into a product display for Drupal 7 Commerce or would you recommend to export all these nodes and create a new product display type and add them back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a product reference on a node for that node to be a "Display Node." A simple solution would be to just add that and any other fields you think necessary to the "selling" part of the node's function. You might need an alternative View Mode for the content type if there are items you need displayed or not dependent on circumstances.

Comment: Thank you. My content type is a Course and I want my teachers to create Course nodes but not create their own prices i.e. not give them permissions to edit products, only allow them to select the products. If that's possible, I think I should add a reference field on each Course that points to a product (or product display?) so as to allow the teacher to only choose prices available from existing products, correct? If so, I think this should then be a reference field to a product instead of a product reference field to connect both and display them together. Would that work?

Comment: I'm a bit confused because "Display Nodes" are used in Commerce1, while in Commerce2 they were replaced with "Product Displays," a dedicated entity type. If you're using C1, as I initially thought, you can allow teachers to connect to a product using a limited selection. If C2, connecting to a limited set of "product displays" would make sense, and would allow some flexibility in display options, I think.

Comment: Are there more versions of Commerce for Drupal 7 then?
In any case I'll try out today what you suggest and come back once I got a result.

Comment: This works and was actually very easy to do. I now also understand how Drupal Commerce works better. Thank you, beltouche !